# Oracle Time Difference over a repeating set

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am sure this is an easy problem to solve however I cannot see how no matter which way round I try and look at it.

I am using an Oracle database and I am trying to report on processing times. The system is running a process that picks up incoming files and processes then into the database. As it performs this task it logs when each of the different sections happen and from which source. I've filtered the data to just give me start and end times as that is all I am currently interested in. Example Data

```
5   15/MAY/15 00:37:01  Started
5   15/MAY/15 00:50:45  Finished
5   16/MAY/15 02:07:41  Started
5   16/MAY/15 02:19:16  Finished
5   16/MAY/15 23:20:25  Started
5   16/MAY/15 23:28:53  Finished
5   17/MAY/15 23:16:36  Started
5   17/MAY/15 23:27:51  Finished
5   18/MAY/15 23:31:28  Started
5   18/MAY/15 23:47:41  Finished
5   19/MAY/15 23:44:12  Started
5   20/MAY/15 00:06:17  Finished
5   20/MAY/15 23:33:42  Started
5   20/MAY/15 23:58:16  Finished
```

What I am trying to get is the duration for each of the "sets" (Start time to End Time). When there is only a single occurence on a day its easy, however when looking at days such as the 16th where there are two sets in a single day, or where it starts on the 19th and ends on the 20th I am struggling. I know this would be possible within a programming language, however I am sure it must also be possible within Oracle as well.

The output I'd expect form the above is:

```
Source  StartTime               EndTime
5       15/MAY/15 00:37:01      15/MAY/15 00:50:45
5       16/MAY/15 02:07:41      16/MAY/15 02:19:16
5       16/MAY/15 23:20:25      16/MAY/15 23:28:53
5       17/MAY/15 23:16:36      17/MAY/15 23:27:51
5       18/MAY/15 23:31:28      18/MAY/15 23:47:41
5       19/MAY/15 23:44:12      20/MAY/15 00:06:17
5       20/MAY/15 23:33:42      20/MAY/15 23:58:16
```

Thanks,

Comment: please, could you provide your pl/sql block?

Comment: It looks like you should consider the analytic function, lag, with the processing dates.  My favorite explanation of these functions are here, http://www.orafaq.com/node/55.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with function [lead()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm):

```
select tsource, starttime, endtime
  from (
    select tsource, ttime starttime, status,
        lead(ttime) over (partition by tsource order by ttime) endtime 
      from test)
  where status = 'Started'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2f021/1)

---

Edit: 
If there may happen that you have two rows with status *Started* consecutively without *Finished* between 
then you need some protection against such situation, for instance this displays null:

```
select tsource, starttime, endtime
  from (
    select tsource, ttime starttime, status,
        case when lead(status) over (partition by tsource order by ttime) = 'Finished'
          then lead(ttime) over (partition by tsource order by ttime)  
          else null
        end endtime
      from test)
  where status = 'Started'
```

Comment: Thanks! You read my mind about the validation in there. I'd not long started trying to adapt your query to cover it when you replied! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

As Patrick Bacon mentioned in a comment, you can use the lead and lag [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm) to peek ahead and behind each row. If the row you are looking at is 'Started' then you need to peak at the next row (chronologically, for the same source) to get the matching 'Finished' row, using `lead`. Conversely, if the row you are looking at is 'Finished' then you need to peak at the previous row to get the matching 'Started' row, using `lag`:

```
    select distinct source,
      case when action = 'Started' then time
        else lag(time) over (partition by source order by time) end as starttime,
      case when action = 'Finished' then time
        else lead(time) over (partition by source order by time) end as endtime
    from t
    order by source, starttime;

    SOURCE STARTTIME           ENDTIME           
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         5 2015-05-15 00:37:01 2015-05-15 00:50:45
         5 2015-05-16 02:07:41 2015-05-16 02:19:16
         5 2015-05-16 23:20:25 2015-05-16 23:28:53
         5 2015-05-17 23:16:36 2015-05-17 23:27:51
         5 2015-05-18 23:31:28 2015-05-18 23:47:41
         5 2015-05-19 23:44:12 2015-05-20 00:06:17
         5 2015-05-20 23:33:42 2015-05-20 23:58:16
```

Because you're looking ahead and behind, you end up with duplicate pairs of data; here I've used `distinct` to squash those duplicates, but you could also use this as a subquery and filter the results.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1963) with a CTE to provide your sample data.